# Parsing to 16-bit value in second complement form

Tags: javascript, parsing, raw-data

The datasheet put me 2 byte for a data, which is defined as :

"These two byte is a 16-bit value in 2's complement form, whose range is from 0xF800 (-4096) to 0x07FF (4095)"

I don't really understand how to parse this data in javascript.

Comment: The data sheet is wrong - `0xf800...0x07ff` is actually `-2048...2047`

Comment: notwithstanding the error, to answer your question we'd need to now how this data is arriving in your application, and how it's currently stored.

Comment: Yes, this is what i thought too. As i know, values weren't good. I wiil call them.
Well, my data is arriving in raw data that i parse in uint8Array. Maybe i have to change the type of these 2 bytes to have the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All current mainstream browsers support the [`DataView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView) class.

Given your `Uint8Array` containing e.g. `[0xf8, 0x00]`:

```
var a = new Uint8Array([0xf8, 0x00])
```

you can treat this as array of `Int16` values instead:

```
var view = new DataView(a.buffer)
var val = view.getInt16(0, false);   // false for big-endian
> -2048
```

If the data in your array is the other way around (little-endian) supply `true` for the second parameter to `.getInt16()`.